# Pandas DataFrame.to_sql() doesn't work anymore with an sqlalchemy 2.0.1 engine.connect() as a context manager and doesn't throw any error

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, contextmanager

This code with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html) `1.5.3` and [sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) `2.0.1` is not working anymore and surprisingly, it doesn't raises any error, the code passes silently:

```py
# python 3.10.6
import pandas as pd # 1.5.3
import psycopg2 # '2.9.5 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)'
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # 2.0.1


def connector():
    return psycopg2.connect(**DB_PARAMS)

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://', creator=connector)

with engine.connect() as connection:
    df.to_sql(
        name='my_table',
        con=connection,
        if_exists='replace',
        index=False,
    )
```

Currently, with sqlalchemy `2.0.1` my table is no more populated with the DataFrame content.

Whereas it was correctly populated with sqlalchemy version `1.4.45`.

#### Edit

Apparently, it works when I ***don't*** use a context manager:

```py
connection = engine.connect()

res.to_sql(
    name='my_table',
    con=connection,
    if_exists='replace',
    index=False
)
Out[2]: 133 # <- wondering what is this return code '133' here?

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

How could I get it to work with a context manager (aka a `with` statement)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The context manager that you are using rolls back on exit. Instead, use `engine.begin()`, which will commit.

```py
with engine.begin() as connection:
    df.to_sql(
        name='my_table',
        con=connection,
        if_exists='replace',
        index=False,
    )
```

Comment: Okay, got it, thanks for your answer, it seems to work. Do you know some readings about this difference of behaviour of sqlalchemy 2.0.1?

Comment: [Migrating to SQLAlchemy 2.0](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html) should be helpful. I'm not sure that Pandas 1.5.3 is 100% compatible with SQLA 2.0, you might need to remain on 1.4.x for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. It seems related to SQLAlchemy v2.x.x.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35594
Reverted back to version 1.4.17 and works properly now.

Comment: Or, upgrade pandas to version ≥ 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the `engine` instance instead of the `connection` instance to the `to_sql` method:

```
engine = create_engine( url = `YOUR_URL`

df.to_sql(
    name='my_table',
    con=engine,
    if_exists='replace',
    index=False,
)
```